# How do I ensure that the "formatting" edit I am reviewing does not add [undeclared] changes to the code being formatted?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, diff

A lot of edits to be reviewed does the formatting; like turning

code code code code
code code code code
code code code code
code code code code

into

```
code code code code
code code cOde code
code code code code
code code code code
```

This is not a major change, but in the difference viewer it is visible as big red block and big green block.

That way somebody can deliberately or by mistake change the code a bit, and this change will not be visible because of "it's just formatting, so big diff is expected".

Should I always scrutinize the diff to find other undeclared edits beside formatting? Is there "ignore whitespace" mode for diffs like in Git?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the markup view, not the rendered output view.  There you can see that the entirety of the diff is spaces for such a change, or not just spaces if they've changed something else.